# How do I copy equations from one MS Word (2019, Mac) document to another without inserting a border around the newly pasted image?

Tags: microsoft-word

I wrote many equations into two documents. If I copy and paste equations into the other document they turn into images (which is fine), but a border is also added around the images. How do I prevent or easily remove the border?

E.g. [image]

If I right-click on the pasted image I am unable to select "Format Picture":

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of this? What do you mean by equations? And it's best if you are specific on which version of word you have.

Comment: @Sickest see updated question

Comment: Just a guess that the default formatting for pasted images is to show a border around it.  If so, you'd have to find where to change it globally.  But you could always go into the format settings for the pasted image and set it to no border.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm not able to format the image; see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Save as .docx (not .doc), then copy equations.

Comment: I wold like to suggest that instead of post this as an answer should be posted as comments, refer this https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer help you to improve the post !!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read anything about posting answers as comments in the link you provided. It would be really helpful if you explained why a comment is better (or provide a link that mentions when to comment vs. when to answer --I am willing to conform). IMO I don't see why a comment would be more useful; it's not like I haven't provided enough detail in my question (people who will face the same issue most likely will not realize they are using a .doc instead of a .docx --including this bit of info in the question would be like answering the question inside the question itself).

Comment: ,, since it's single sentence text also the answer needs some illustration to be more meaningful !

Comment: I don't think I need to illustrate how to change a file name. The question itself has plenty of illustration.